# How to send HTTP get method with headers using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to send GET Request method with the below  headers . 
I am getting the following capture from HTTP live headers

---

```
***http://172.20.22.26/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.20.22.26
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bWl0aHVuOm1pdGh1bg==

HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2009 00:29:20 GMT
Server: HTTPsrv
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------**------------------------------*
```

I am using the following program . It is not working . Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
  <?php 

 $credentials = "mithun:mithun";

 $url = "http://172.20.22.26";
 $headers = array(
"GET /HTTP/1.1",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1",
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",            "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
"Keep-Alive: 300",      
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $defined_vars['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);               

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
 if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
  print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
 else {  
 // Show me the result
 var_dump($data);
 curl_close($ch);
  }?>
```

Comment: GET is not a header ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to send all of those parameters through, the only ones you need are

```
Host: 172.20.22.26
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bWl0aHVuOm1pdGh1bg==
```

the other headers come from the server's reply, and you won't need to set the  GET /HTTP/1.1 as it's implicit in the request anyway.

Comment: Probably, the only header the OP actually has to send is the Authorization.

Comment: possibly, and user-agent too if necessary. depends what s/he's trying to test

Comment: But I am not able get the html page back . How do I do that ?

Comment: are you getting anything back? i can't test with your server since it's down but using essentially the same code with http://www.google.com/ in it, seems to work. also you'll want to leave out the `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` line unless you're prepared to ungzip stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE  to include the header in the output.