# I am getting error while trying to get profile details from Fitbit using api. What is the reason?

Tags: php, oauth, http-headers, fitbit

Error is,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [errorType] => oauth
                    [fieldName] => n/a
                    [message] => No Authorization header provided in the request. Each call to Fitbit API should be OAuth signed
                )

        )

)
```

I am using Oauth library. I have already got user token.

```
http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/23Q/profile.json?oauth_consumer_key=425e1234b8823e26485aa6&oauth_nonce=31f991c9b3e068c14adceddd9b862c0a&oauth_signature=R5oi4dHA6ztIIpdKheahYOy%2FeMQ%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1348821623&oauth_token=3405b4918d5d96a7b78885a98&oauth_version=1.0
```

I tried this...

$url = http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/23Q2SP/profile.json;

$header = array();
    $header[] = "Authorization: OAuth 3405b496578885a98";

```
$header[] = "Accept: ";

$header[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$header[] = "Pragma: no-cache";   
$this->http_info = array();
$ci = curl_init();
/* Curl settings */
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ci);
```

BUT THE SAME ERROR
{"errors":[{"errorType":"oauth","fieldName":"n/a","message":"No Authorization header provided in the request. Each call to Fitbit API should be OAuth signed"}]}

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Fitbit API, but what I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fitbit-api/Fk7yOWqHhB8) is that, Fitbit allow GET requests only through authorization header, so you might have to set header something like

```
"Authorization: OAuth <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.fitbit.com
```

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607040/how-to-send-http-get-method-with-headers-using-curl) on how to set headers through CURL, hope that helps.

Comment: I tried it with access token. But the same error returned.My sample request is,                                                         GET /1/user/-/activities/date/2010-04-02.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.fitbit.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="fitbit-example-client-application",
oauth_token="8d3221fb072f31b5ef1b3bcfc5d8a27a",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1270248088",
oauth_nonce="515379974",
oauth_signature="Gf5NUq1Pvg3DrtxHJyVaMXq4Foo%3D"
oauth_version="1.0"                                                 How can i add this in my header?

Comment: i guess you just pass oauth_token like `Authorization: OAuth 8d3221fb072f31b5ef1b3bcfc5d8a27a`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
req_url = 'http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token';
$authurl = 'http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token';
$acc_url = 'http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize';

$conskey = 'Dev key';
$conssec = 'Dev secret';

$token = 'User token';
$secret = 'User secret';



try {

    $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
    $oauth->enableDebug();



     $oauth->setToken($token,$secret);


      $oauth->fetch("http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2013-12-06.json");
    $response_info = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();

  print_r($oauth->getLastResponse());

  } catch(OAuthException $E) {
  print_r($E);
}
```